# Visual planning tool for Windows Server Task scheduler?

Tags: windows, windows-server, task-management

I'm managing for myself a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 machine which host things like SVN server, SQL Server, bugtracker, etc.

I am using Windows task scheduler to perform various maintenance and backup operations. Most of these operations must not overlap, so I carefully plan them using an Excel file to have a quick overview of what starts when, but of course it's not really efficient (error prone, needs to manually maintain the file, etc)

So I was wondering if there is a visual tool, like a daily hour per hour planning to see which task starts up at which hour based on defined schedules in Task Scheduler ? On each row the day of week, on each column the hours, and at intersection each task which starts at the time.

I guess this is the daily routine of a network/server administrator, but I am not myself one and I can't afford a professional task scheduler for my simple needs.

It could even be better if the tool was able to also retrieve the actual (last) duration of the task, as the scheduler is displaying it. Also, it would be a great feature to have the status of each task (faulty or successful) but both are not a requirement.

I hope it's the right place for my question, please let me know if I should ask it on "ServerFault" instead.

Have you ever heard of a such tool ? Thank you

Comment: AFract, why you don't want to use [**nnCron**](https://github.com/nnCron/nnCron)? It have more features, than built-in Windows Task Scheduler. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [TaskSchedulerView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/task_scheduler_view.html) - it has a lot of columns and info, all available to be exported as XML/TXT/CSV

> TaskSchedulerView is a simple tool for Windows Vista/7/8/10 that displays in a single table the list of all tasks from the Task Scheduler of Windows. It also allows you to easily disable/enable mutiple tasks at once. For every task, the following information is displayed: Task Name, Description, Status, Hidden (Yes/No), Last Run/Next Run Times, Task Folder, EXE filename or COM handler of the task, number of missed runs, and more...

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it lacks the "visual" planning feature and the log of previous executions of each task, but apart this it's really interesting, especially for the various "Report" features. Thank you!